# XAMPP bad request

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, http, xampp

I'm trying to connect with `Apache server (XAMPP)`, but it gives me respond like:

```
192.168.1.103 - - [26/Jun/2017:13:32:31 +0200] "GET /create_sqlite.php?id_card=1398036&action=wejscie HTTP/1.0" 400 981 "-" "-"
```

I've checked 400 error, which means, that server doesn't understand me. And I don't know why.

What I've already done:

```
1. I changed my Skype settings (it blocks 80,443 ports - now not:) )
2. I've uncomment some interesting linesin php.ini:

    extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
    extension=php_sqlite3.dll
    sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"
```

And still nothing. 
Actually it was running some time ago, but I had to do format disc (sad story ;) ) and I've lost my `XAMPP`. Now, when I got it again it doesn't want to cooperate.

Comment: when an entry appears in de Apache logs it means the request at least came through to Apache (Skype is not blocking you)
is every simple script giving this error, or only this one?

Comment: Hello @Ivo P
I've created test.php:
<?php

$id_card = $_GET['id_card'];
$action = $_GET['action'];

echo $id_card;
echo $action;

?>

And answer was actually the same:
192.168.1.103 - - [26/Jun/2017:14:13:52 +0200] "GET /test.php?id_card=1398036&action=wejscie HTTP/1.0" 400 981 "-" "-"

So now I know that connection with database is not a problem here.

Comment: Hello @IvoP ;)
I wrote even simple echo and still nothing :/

Comment: so, is php installed (properly)?

Comment: I hope! :) I've just open php file in my browser (localhost/test.php and any other) and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with HTTP syntax? Is it possible?

Comment: I need to add one more important info:
I've opened phpinfo.php in my browser and in XAMPP access.log file there appeared:
::1 - - [27/Jun/2017:09:06:46 +0200] "GET /dashboard/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 95847 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

BUT I copy the same request to my program and in log file I've got:
192.168.1.112 - - [27/Jun/2017:09:18:48 +0200] "GET /dashboard/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 400 981 "-" "-"

So, actually...I can't see the difference.